# Create a table in a new sheet with data from two different tables in two different sheets in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

I am new to Excel and is currently struggling to get intermediate formulas right.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve.

A) I have three sheets,

1. EMPLOYEE, 2. PROJECTS and 3. ENGAGEMENT

B) EMPLOYEE sheet contains information about an employee. Employee ID (EMP_ID) is generated from the name entered.

C) PROJECTS sheet contains information about the projects handled or being handled. Project ID is generated from the name of the project. Most important part is the column "Resource 1" through "Resource 20" for now. As of now, a project can have maximum of 20 resources allocated to it. One can select resources from the drop-down list.

What I am trying to achieve is,

1. On "ENGAGEMENT" sheet, all the projects where a resource is engaged needs to appear under "Project 1" through "Project 10" columns (assuming that a person can work on maximum of 10 projects).
2. I need to show stats for projects between START and END date in ENGAGEMENT sheet. However, this is not of highest priority.

Please note that, I want to achieve this with formulae only, not script or macro.

Please look at the attached screenshots and the sheet I've attached.

Thanks,
Dave

Screenshots and references can be downloaded from below given links.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTcjW.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLyZI.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeoTj.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgDiW.jpg
[5]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qikvz4X6bvKO8PyB_nrmZA64x6StUMlh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109764009612506156621&rtpof=true&sd=true
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and narrow down your question. People are unlikely to bother to download five files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(IFNA(VLOOKUP(TRIM(A3:A), 
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(
 IF((PROJECTS!D2:D4="")*(PROJECTS!C2:C4<>""), TODAY(), PROJECTS!D2:D4), PROJECTS!C2:C4)>
 SEQUENCE(1, 1000, ), ROW(PROJECTS!A2:A4)&"×"&PROJECTS!C2:C4+SEQUENCE(1, 1000, )+1, )), 
 "where Col1 is not null")&"×"&TRANSPOSE(QUERY(FLATTEN(
 IF(PROJECTS!I2:4="",,ROW(PROJECTS!A2:A4)&"×"&PROJECTS!I2:4&"×"&PROJECTS!A2:A4)), 
 "where Col1 is not null"))), "×"), "select max(Col5) where Col1=Col3 "&
 IF(D1="",," and Col2>="&VALUE(D1))&
 IF(F1="",," and Col2<="&VALUE(F1))&
 " group by Col5 pivot Col4"),,9^9))), " ", "×", 1), "×"), 2, 0)), " ")))
```

[image: iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii]

Comment: Hi player0,

To be honest, I have never seen such a complex and long formula in my life. After searching a bit I understood that, it is kind of dynamic array formula, which is absolutely new to me. So, please pardon me if I am doing something foolish.

I have copied and pasted the formula you have provided into C3. The moment I press ENTER (also tried CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER), I get an error stating "That function isn't valid" and SPLIT is highlighted.

Could you please guide me further?

Thanks, Dave.

Comment: @DaveGueldner here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rijCeJe91rYQVgVfkBVhtLT0Q0uZePDaftf_Ew6hPqM/edit#gid=244774370

Comment: thanks for your help. However, I'm still struggling to get it working as I intend it to work.

1. If you check the sheet which you've shared with me, you'll find that, I have added a new person under EMPLOYEE i.e. SAM_GRU and also added a new project HELL_WOR under PROJECTS.

2. DAVI_MON, SUKH_S. and SAM_GRU has been assigned to HELL_WOR.

I expected the ENGAGEMENT sheet to reflect the changes which it didn't do. Obviously I'm doing something wrong. But, can't understand what.

Finally, as I have pointed, the formula works with Google Sheet. However, it doesn't with MS Excel.

Comment: @DaveGueldner in PROJECTS!C4 you need a date. then see PROJECTS!K4 and EMPLOYEE!A6 where is extra space so if these two do not match you won't get any results. this formula is only for google sheets. half of the used functions are not supported by MS Excel

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Tried and works as expected. However, was hoping to find a way with Excel. But anyway, this will work for now.

Comment: Hi player0. Finally populated the sheet with the data and made necessary modifications. But, ENGAGEMENT sheet doesn't work anymore. I don't care about the projects which don't have dates associated with them. But as you can see, formula breaks. Presumably it has something to the ranges (seems like it is taking only 3 rows into consideration) in the formula. I am unable to fix it as it is way too advance formula for me. Kindly help me.

Sheet is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMJPU2iI_BjpAv1XbBSDuZuT4eyTobVu_v3y9GJyHH8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @DaveGueldner edited, see your sheet